# Query Selector, Where Clause comparing dates

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get the selective data from a Sheet.

I am getting Column U in comparision with Column P

```
Column U = Unique Data
Column P = Date and Time Associated with it.
```

```
Column U        Column P
564865          2020-06-13 5:52:00
```

I would like to get the data of the day before current day while truncating time of Column P.

i am trying to use this query, but i am getting some error.

```
=QUERY('Shopify Unfulfilled'!1:2615,"Select U WHERE "&LEFT('Shopify Unfulfilled'!P:P,10)& "=" &TODAY()-1&"")
```

ERROR:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "Created "" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works

```
=QUERY('Shopify Unfulfilled'!1:2615,"Select U WHERE todate (P) = date '"&TEXT(today() -1, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 1)
```